# Neither sort -n nor sort -g will sort my file correctly

Tags: sorting

I have a file that has three columns that needs sorting to the third column, which has floating point numbers. Neither -n nor -g give me the correct order:

```
sort -gk3 < testing
  -15.0963697       868.897461       96.8553619    
  -13.8969107       868.917542       97.6257935    
  -14.4861879       868.907837       97.2293854    
  -12.2185059       868.942627       98.9011612    
  -12.7650061       868.934814       98.4643097    
  -13.3239822       868.926392       98.0385132    
  -11.1592150       868.956848       99.8029022    
  -11.6834946       868.949951       99.3477020    
  -8.21321392       868.989685       102.681389    
  -8.68218231       868.985168       102.186371    
  -7.29956532       868.997864       103.687309    
  -7.75242090       868.993896       103.181770    
   12.0171452       868.944519       151.410812    
   12.0415277       868.944214       151.398087    
   12.0650854       868.943909       151.383926    
   12.0877380       868.943542       151.368332    
   12.1094027       868.943359       151.351395    
   12.1299915       868.942993       151.333176    
   12.1494293       868.942688       151.313751    



sort -nk3 < testing
  -8.68218231       868.985168       102.186371    
  -8.21321392       868.989685       102.681389    
  -7.75242090       868.993896       103.181770    
  -7.29956532       868.997864       103.687309    
   12.1494293       868.942688       151.313751    
   12.1299915       868.942993       151.333176    
   12.1094027       868.943359       151.351395    
   12.0877380       868.943542       151.368332    
   12.0650854       868.943909       151.383926    
   12.0415277       868.944214       151.398087    
   12.0171452       868.944519       151.410812    
  -15.0963697       868.897461       96.8553619    
  -14.4861879       868.907837       97.2293854    
  -13.8969107       868.917542       97.6257935    
  -13.3239822       868.926392       98.0385132    
  -12.7650061       868.934814       98.4643097    
  -12.2185059       868.942627       98.9011612    
  -11.6834946       868.949951       99.3477020    
  -11.1592150       868.956848       99.8029022
```

sort -n apparently has issues recognizing the decimal point as such, turning 99.something to a higher value than 100.something, due to the leading digit. sort -g doesn't do this, but as you see from lines 2 and 3/first example above it doesn't treat anyhing *after* the decimal point correctly.

Funny thing is I couldn't find any pointers to any lost souls that encountered the same issue, though it should be a very common task. sort versions (from coreutils) tested were 8.4 and 8.30.

TIA
Rimsy

Comment: From [the source code](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/sort.c#L2031), you can see that `-g` uses `strtold`, which is [documented](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtof) as using the current C locale. You can set a breakpoint there to see how the string is being parsed.

Comment: The above commands both work for me with your data. What's your localle? `LC_ALL`, `LC_COLLATE`, `LC_CTYPE` (or `LANG`, if `LC_CTYPE` is unset) environment variables can all change the sort behavior, including introducing undefined behavior for bad combinations.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html

Comment: Yes, correct - locale was set to de_DE. Changing this to C (setenv LC_ALL C) fixes the order. I'm scolding myself; I knew about this from investigating my problem. I'm using tcshell, and tried set LC_ALL=C, but this was not enough - I should have issued setenv LC_ALL C. Thanks for your replies.